# TypeError with ">="

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm learning Python.
I'm writing some simple programs to learn the basics.
Yesterday, i was trying to write a program with "if-else statement", but it don't work because of this error:

**-TypeError: '>=' non supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.-**

What does it means?

Below is the code, that I am using :

```
print(' Insert a value to "a":  ')

a= input()

if a >= 1:
     print('G')     # random letter
```

Comment: That error clearly states that you are trying to compare a string with an integer which you can't do in python !

Comment: Well,  what would "my string is greater or equal to 1" mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: `trying to write a program whit "if-else statement", but it don't work`. How do we know what code you've tried. Please post code snippet for us to understand.

Comment: Take a look now.

Comment: However, guys keep calm! Is my first post

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to compare the values of a string and an integer, which won't work.

For example, let's say you have `string = "hello"` and `integer = 1`. You cannot say that one of these values is greater than or equal to the other one, so you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

One of the important things is to understand how does the function input() works.
As mentioned in the comment you cannot compare string with int, so how to get this working if the input is int.

**How the input function works in Python :**

1. When input() function executes program flow will be stopped until the user has given an input.
2. The text or message display on the output screen to ask a user to enter input value is optional i.e. the prompt, will be printed on the screen is optional.
3. Whatever you enter as input, input function convert it into a string. if you enter an integer value still input() function convert it into a string. You need to explicitly convert it into an integer in your code using typecasting.

i just added typecasting to your code to make it work.

```
print(' Insert a value to "a":  ')

a= int(input())

if a >= 1:
     print('G')
```